# Embed Angular Within HTML created by Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table declared statically with html and the quantity of table rows is dependent on information stored on a database. The cells are created using Javascripts insertRow function and I can access the TD element by using table.row[x].cells[y]. My goal is to insert Angular's md-button in place of the HTML button attribute I created using .innerHTML.

Comment: creating codepen will update soon

Comment: code: https://codepen.io/walkerdude5/pen/XOWJJB

what I want the button to do: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzbQRV?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular - then you should use the ng-repeat (or *ngFor in Angular 2+) directives to add the content to the page instead of using javascript. The following will give a table with two rows and 3 tds per tr.

**So its really more a case of getting your data, adding it to $scope and formatting it in a way that you can iterate over in the ng-repeat.**

If you really want to keep it the way yuo have it - then simple create a button and styling it with the stylnig to make it look like the button you like.

```js
var angularTest = angular.module('angularDiv',[]);

angularTest.controller('tableController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.items= [
    { contents: ['content 1.1', 'content 1.2','content 1.3']},
    { contents: ['content 2.1', 'content 2.2','content 2.3']},
  ];
}])
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse}
th {
 border: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background: #ededed;
 border-bottom-width: 2px
 }
 
 td {
 border: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="angularDiv">
  <table ng-controller="tableController">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="heading in items[0].contents">
          Heading {{$index + 1}}
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
       <td ng-repeat ="content in item.contents">{{content}}</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I give td the ng-repeat property through javascript?